# send a text with ajax and receive a response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

Hmm I have a little problem with that :

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          name : 'aatrox'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      url: 'appliserv/testsendajax.php',
      success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          alert('good');
      },
      error: function(data){
          console.log(data);
          alert(fail);
      }
  });
```

the text in the alert is always fail ....
in my serv :

```
$text = $_POST['name'];

echo $text;
```

and I don't understand that. Thanks (sry if my english isn't good)

Comment: what does data look like in the console

Comment: You are missing `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: sure :Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
progress: function () {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "aatrox"

Comment: etRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
state: function () {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress */ ) {
__proto__: Object
I add ontentType: "application/json" but not work.

Comment: Change `dataType: "json"` to `dataType: "text"`. Since you output plain text on server-side

Comment: Shouldn't `alert(fail);` be `alert('fail');`?

Comment: @hindmost thx !! thx a lot i haven't see that ... !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server-side script output plain text. So you have to change value of `dataType` option.

Change this:

```
dataType: "json"
```

to this:

```
dataType: "text"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely you're getting a `parse error`. This is because your ajax request is expecting `JSON` but you're are returning a plain `string`. Either return `JSON` from your `PHP` script or change the `dataType` to `text`:

```
dataType: "text",
```

Also be sure to change `alert(fail);` to:

```
alert('fail');
```

String literals must be delimited or variables have to be initialized before they are used.

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answer, I just want to add that using

```
async: false
```

is a bad practice when dealing with ajax calls, it freezes your browser while waiting for the response. 
If it's possible you should try to avoid this behavior and use
instead the ajax callbacks properly; however if you really want to block the UI you can try to use something like http://malsup.com/jquery/block/